# Como parar e reiniciar uma função JQuery que pode ser acionada por diversos elementos?

Tags: jquery, funções, input

Olá,

Fiz uma tela com um teclado virtual, para uma aplicação touch screen. O cliente quer dois inputs na mesma tela e quando o usuário selecionar um input, o teclado deve inserir os valores digitados nesse mesmo input. Tenho a função funcionando, mas o problema é que a cada vez que eu seleciono um input, múltiplas instâncias da função continuam rodando.

Por exemplo: Se toco 3 vezes no input 1 e uma vez no input 2 e depois digito "Q" no teclado, é inserido no input 1 "QQQ" e no input 2 "Q", tudo ao mesmo tempo. Como posso parar e reiniciar a função cada vez que um elemento input seja selecionado?

O nome da função é `termoConsulta(param)`. Estou usando método `click()` para selecionar o input.

```
$('#input1').click(function(){
    termoConsulta('#input1');
});
$('#input2').click(function(){
    termoConsulta('#input2');
});

function termoConsulta($escreveInput){

        $('#teclado li').click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is("#consultar")) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    digito = $this.html();

                if($this.hasClass('tecla-x')){
                    var entrada = $escreveInput.val();
                    //apaga último dígito
                    $escreveInput.val(entrada.substr(0,entrada.length-1));
                    return false;
                }

                //escreve o dígito no input
                $escreveInput.val($escreveInput.val()+digito);
            }
        });

        //apaga TUDO
        $('#apagar').click(function(){
            $escreveInput.val('');
        });     
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código da função termoConsulta. já tentou associar o evento a chamada da função?

Comment: @DavidVinicius adicionei o código. Como posso associar à chamada? Desculpe a ignorância, estou aprendendo a programar ainda.

Comment: Você quer dizer no arquivo HTML, com OnClick()?

Comment: é tipo isso, tente usar o Onclick.

Comment: Acabei resolvendo retirando a função. Agora existe simplesmente um comando no código, e toda vez que um elemento é clicado, as instruções são chamadas. Funciona como o Onclick. Obrigado @DavidVinicius